# Remove dust bubble from glass screen protector?

Tags: technology

So I just got a glass screen protector for my iPad & while applying it, a speck of dust got trapped and caused a bubble. Now the bubble is on the edge of the device and not on the screen itself, so it doesn't bother me too much, but I would like to get rid of it. Can I remove it without removing the entire screen protector? Also, if I am unable to remove it, will it expand over time to get to the screen eventually, or will it stay as it is?

[image: bubble]

Update: I ended up just prying it up with a credit card, not the whole protector but just a small portion, removing the dust from underneath using the card, and then setting it back down without any bubbles.

Comment: It shouldn't expand any more, but removing it is still the best option

Answer (score 3):

Recently I also tried to apply a glass protector and failed terribly, but somehow with the help of a friend I rescued it and removed all bubbles. The trick is using cello-tape. Attach a cello-tape to your screen protector, and slowly lift it, once its done, take a piece of the tape and attach it between your thumb and index finger, and tap on the glass protector where you can spot dust particles. The glue on the tape will make the dust cling on to the tape and make your protector free of the dust. Repeat this for all the dust particles, and slowly put back the protector. Hope that helps.

Comment: This should be done before applying the screen protector.

Comment: I tried this, but the screen protector does not come off..

Comment: @mayankbudhwani this should work, and if you have trouble lifting the corner you try using something sharp and flat to get started. Of course care bit to scratch anything

Comment: @mayankbudhwani Please try attaching the Cello Tape to the corner of the Screen Protector.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an extremely sharp knife, you can sometimes make a small incision and then use a credit card or something similar to push all the air out via this incision, which then disappears due to the small size.

The knife must be really sharp as to make as small hole as possible with as little tearing as possible.